# Alert box in python using turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

How can I make an alert box appear when I am running a program using turtle graphics? We have textinput() but it asks user to input something but I just want to show some text there. Is that possible with turtle graphics?

Comment: Why not just use tkinter for alert?

Comment: I am currently learning turtle. Is there any way to do so using turtle?

Comment: No. Turtle use Tkinter, you have to use it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import messagebox
  
root = Tk()
  
messagebox.showinfo("showinfo", "Information") # The alert.
  
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Really? Is this what the question asks? Is this about turtle?

Comment: @Apostolos - turtle runs on top of Tkinter.

Comment: The question been changed! It now talks about "turtle". My answer was about tkinter because the question was about "tkinter".  See  also my comment  above. I couldn't miss that hard! 

Answer (score 1):

I found SecretLloyd's answer helpful to find what I needed, but it also results in an additional empty Tk window loading on the screen next to the turtle window.

Digging a bit deeper, the `turtle` module imports `tkinter as TK`, so instead of importing tkinter separately, we can just invoke the message box through the turtle module's reference.

These tests were done in Python 3.11, but without digging into the turtle module changelogs, I would think this works is most or all versions.

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen, TK

t = Turtle()
t.shape("turtle")
t.color("green")
t.forward(100)

TK.messagebox.showinfo(title="The Turtle says:", message="Time for a nap!")

Screen().exitonclick()
```

alternatively:

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.shape("turtle")
t.color("green")
t.forward(100)

turtle.TK.messagebox.showinfo(title="The Turtle says:", message="Time for a nap!")

turtle.exitonclick()
```